# WP7 Periodic Task - What can I do within it

Tags: windows-phone-7, background

For a WP7 app I have managed to get a PeriodTask running as per some examples on msdn (sends out a toast message).  Now looking to extend to do what I want.

The task is running in the background and I have no need for it to communicate with the foreground app if that is running.   I am just a little unsure of what I am allowed to do within this background task, and what code I can access from it.

I would like to be able to access the database  that I am using (Sterling) and then update a live tile.    Presumably, since its running independently then I will need to open the database - do what I need to do re the tile  and then close the database within  this background process. This should be okay?   And from within my ScheduledAgent class OnInvoke method I can call code that is defined on a class in my foreground project as long as I include a reference to that project in my ScheduledTask project.    There are no issues with that code running inside my Background Periodic Task application?

- thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a BackgroundAgent you can do anything **apart** from use the APIs in the unsupported list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962(v=vs.92).aspx

The "Marketplace Test Kit" will detect use of any unsupported APIs.

Comment: Also, you can't reference any assemblies using either of those unsupported APIs. (Which makes shared-code somewhat painful)

Comment: Great - thanks to you both.  I can see that sharing code could be a little tricky if you are using some of the unsupported APIs.

Comment: In my Periodic task (which is in the scheduletaskproject) I was planning to reference my Mainproject to run some code there to update the live tile.   But I cannot add the Mainproject as a reference to the ScheduleTaskproject as that would cause a circular reference. So, I will need to carefully refactor code into some sort of common project?   Presumably this is an issue to work through with the scheduledTaskProject depending upon what it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I added a small Data Model project where I created a class to represent the data/model.
From the main app I store that instantiated object to the isolated storage. In the scheduletaskproject you can then just retrieve that stored instance from isolated storage if you also reference the small Model project.

If I'm not mistaken there is also a 5mb memory limit. So using a DB inside the  scheduletaskproject could be a problem ( reference: http://csainty.blogspot.com/2011/08/wp75-mangobackground-agents.html )